# How to make Searching in Codeigniter where i have 3 categories of checkboxes?

Tags: codeigniter

How to make a search and get from database in codeigniter where i used 3 different checkbox categories..

This is what i have in my HTML Page...

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('regularSearch') ?>" method="POST">                       

<h1>Marital Status</h1>                                     

            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="marital_status[]" value="Never Married">
                    Never Married
            </label>                    

            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="marital_status[]" value="Widowed">
                    Widowed
            </label>                    

            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="marital_status[]" value="Divorced">
                    Divorced 
            </label>                    

            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="marital_status[]" value="Awaiting divorce">
                    Awaiting divorce 
            </label>


<h1>Mother Tongues</h1>                         
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="motherTongue[]" value="English" checked>
                    English
            </label>                    

            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="motherTongue[]" value="Polish">
                    Polish
            </label>

            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="motherTongue[]" value="French">
                    French
            </label>


<h1>Show profile</h1>           
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="showProfiles[]" value="Imagesecure_No" checked>
                    With Photo
            </label>                

            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="showProfiles[]" value="Horosc_YES">
                    With Horoscope
            </label>

            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="showProfiles[]" value="online">
                    Online right now 
            </label>                
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="showProfiles[]" value="Premium_YES">
                    Premium members 
            </label>

<input type="submit" name="submit">                 

</form>
```

### My Search Query

```
    public function searchRegular()
    {
        $maritalArray = $this->input->post('marital_status');
        $motherArray = $this->input->post('motherTongue');
        $showProfArray = $this->input->post('showProfiles');

        if($this->input->post('marital_status'))
        {
            foreach($maritalArray as $maritalRow)
            {
                $this->db->or_having('Marital_status', $maritalRow);                
            }
        }

        if($this->input->post('motherTongue'))
        {
            foreach($motherArray as $motherRows)
            {           
                $this->db->or_having('Mother_tongue', $motherRows); 
            }
        }   

        if($this->input->post('showProfiles'))
        {           
            foreach ($showProfArray as $showProfRow) 
            {               
                $this->db->or_having('Image_secure', $showProfRow);
                $this->db->or_having('Horoscope', $showProfRow);
                $this->db->or_having('Online', $showProfRow);   
                $this->db->or_having('Premium_Memebers', $showProfRow);             
            }   
        }       

        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Please Help... I spend 4 days to figure out how to do this....
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You please explain the error you get?

Comment: Shihas - The problem is if two of the three checkboxes categories' can successfully get datas from database, then when clicked any checkbox of the third category, then the whole program gets messed up.....

Comment: Did you try returning the result as an array `return result_array();` ?

Comment: Yes... But the error is "Trying to get property of non-object"..

Comment: Am i doing the search in correct way ??

Comment: Yes.. Make sure the whether the checkbox value from third category is coming to the `searchRegular()` and about the database table column names.

Comment: and also try `or_like` instead of `or_having`. And you can have `group_start()` aslo.

Comment: Yes, they are correct... Is there any other ideas ??

Comment: `echo $this->db->get_compiled_select(); exit(); ` use this code before `$query = $this->db->get('users');` and check whether your query is right or wrong.

Comment: Thanks... But, it ain't working...

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment you say everything gets messed up if anybody chooses from the 3rd category

its clear that this get messed up - because you iterate over showProfiles without handling the data - which is simply wrong in your case, try the following
(i'm assuming the last category is saved as a 0/1 state in your db)

```
public function searchRegular()
{
    $maritalArray = $this->input->post('marital_status');
    $motherArray = $this->input->post('motherTongue');
    $showProfArray = $this->input->post('showProfiles');

    if($this->input->post('marital_status'))
    {
        foreach($maritalArray as $maritalRow)
        {
            $this->db->or_having('Marital_status', $maritalRow);                
        }
    }

    if($this->input->post('motherTongue'))
    {
        foreach($motherArray as $motherRows)
        {           
            $this->db->or_having('Mother_tongue', $motherRows); 
        }
    }   

    if($this->input->post('showProfiles'))
    {
        foreach ($showProfArray as $showProfRow) 
        {
            switch($showProfRow)
            {
                case "Imagesecure_No":
                    $this->db->or_having('Image_secure', 1);
                    break;
                case "Horosc_YES":
                    $this->db->or_having('Horoscope', 1);
                    break;
                case "online":
                    $this->db->or_having('Online', 1);   
                    break;
                case "Premium_YES":
                    $this->db->or_having('Premium_Memebers', 1);   
                    break;

            }
        }   
    }       

    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    return $query->result();
}
```

If this doesn't help, you should provide an excerpt of your db table structure and explain what exactly you want.

Comment: Thank you sir ... But, i didnt tried your answer..  what i want from the three categories of checkboxes is " if i choose 'widowed' from the first category and 'French' from the second category and 'Horosc_YES' from the third category" and if i click search button i want to get rows from table having all these checked fields...

Comment: thats ok - but how do you store these values - 0=no, 1=yes? thats why i've said you should post an excerpt of your db